# I have code in JAVA and VB that works. I need to do the same thing with PHP, how do I do it

Tags: java, php, vb.net

VB Code that works:

```
Public Function Encrypt(ByVal Data As String) As Byte()
    Dim md5Hasher As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim hashedBytes As Byte()
    Dim encoder As New UTF8Encoding()

    hashedBytes = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(Data))
    Return hashedBytes
End Function
```

JAVA code that works:

```
byte[] bytes = stringToConvert.getBytes("UTF-8");
MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
hashedBytes = m.digest(bytes);
```

What I have tried in PHP that does not work and I think I know why.

I think it is because of this:

Characters in Java are stored as Unicode 16-bit sequences. In PHP they're single byte sequences.
This is the code I have tried...

```
     $UTFbString = UTF8_encode($bString);
     $hashedBytes = md5($UTFbString, true);
```

Ok, I have found that if I use this method...

```
 function ascii_to_dec($str)
 {
     for ($i = 0, $j = strlen($str); $i < $j; $i++) {
     $dec_array[] = ord($str{$i});
  }
   return $dec_array;
  }
```

and this code...

```
 $bStringArr = array( ascii_to_dec($bString));

 I can get back an array that matches the byte array in JAVA.

 So the next challenge is to convert that to bytes then md5 hash those bytes?
```

The JAVA code that does that looks like this...

```
   MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
   byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
   int byteCount;
   while ((byteCount = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
      digester.update(bytes, 0, byteCount);
   }
   byte[] digest = digester.digest();
```

Any suggestions on implementing something something like this in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not sure why one would want to use a byte array as md5 hash, here is my solution:

```
<?php
    $stringToConvert = "äöüß";
    $md5 = md5(utf8_encode($stringToConvert), true);
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($md5); $i++) {
        $c = ord($md5[$i]);
        $b[] = $c > 127 ? $c-256 : $c;
    }
    print_r($b);
?>
```

Comment: All outputs the output from the VB.Code, the JAVA code and the PHP code must match. This did not produce the desired result.

Comment: It depends on how you do the matching. I tried matching it as numbers from -127 to 127. If you want the output to match properly use the standard md5 output pattern. A string consisting of 32 hey characters [0-f]. In PHP it would be just
    $stringToConvert = "äöüß";
    $md5 = md5(utf8_encode($stringToConvert));
Or without utf8_encode(), depending on how you read the string in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php
$hashedBytes = base64_encode(md5($bString, true))
```

Comment: All outputs the output from the JAVA and VB code and PHP code must match. I think this may be getting close to what I need, but did not get me the desired results.